# Let (P, V) be any ZK protocol, then the protocol is WI. --> help with proof

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

In the amazing paper "Witness Indistinguishable and Witness Hiding Protocols
" by Shamir and Feige.

> Theorem 3.3: Let (P, V) be any ZK protocol, then the protocol is WI.

The sketch of the proof involves a distinguisher $D$, which I never saw used in the context of ZK, and I don't know it's definition.

Can you define $D$ ?

Can you point me to the proof of this theorem or just walk me through it loosely?

Answer (score 1):

**TL,DR:** there's already a quite nice proof sketch in the original paper by Feige and Shamir. Check it out [here](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Ercbose/internship/lectures2016/rt02feigeshamir.pdf)! If you want to see an intuitive explanation then keep reading!

***What does witness indistinguishability mean, intuitively?***

Witness indistinguishability (WI): The proof system $(P,V)$ is WI over a relation $R$, if for any instance $x$ the verifier with auxiliary information $y$ cannot distinguish which witness was used in a proof $x\in R$.

> Can you define ?

$D$ is a distinguisher that tries to guess which witness was used to generate the proof. Note, that the distinguisher has only access to the proof's transcript and auxiliary information $y$.

***What does zero knowledge mean, intuitively?***

Zero knowledge (ZK): The proof's transcript $V_{P(w,x)}(x,y)$ and the simulated view $M(x,y;V)$ are indistinguishable.

***Theorem*** *(Feige and Shamir)*: If a proof system $(P,V)$ is zero-knowledge (ZK) then it is also witness indistinguishable (WI).

***Proof sketch***

If the success probability of distinguisher $D$ is $p$ when witness $w_1$ was used, then by the zero-knowledge property of $(P,V)$ the distinguisher's success probability remains the same, even if it runs on a simulated transcript outputted by $M$, i.e. $M(x,y;V)$, because by the zero-knowledge property we have that the simulator's view $M(x,y;V)$ and the verifier's view $V_{P(x,w_1)}(x,y)$ are indistinguishable. Since the simulator's view is independent from the used witness, therefore we also have that the ensembles $M(x,y;V)$ and $V_{P(x,w_2)}(x,y)$ are indistinguishable. By the transitivity of indistinguishability we have that the ensembles $V_{P(x,w_1)}(x,y)$ and $V_{P(x,w_2)}(x,y)$ are indistinguishable, i.e., the protocol $(P,V)$ is WI.

Note, however, that the opposite is not true. There are WI protocols, that are not ZK. An example is taken [from here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Ejkatz/gradcrypto2/NOTES/lecture21.pdf): Assume the existence of a length-preserving one-way permutation $f$ and define the language
$L_0:= \{y |\text{the first bit of } f^{−1}(y)\text{ is } 0 \}$. (Note that every $y\in L_0$ has the unique witness $x = f^{−1}(y)$.) An interactive proof in which the prover sends $f^{−1}(y)$ on common input $y$ is witness indistinguishable (trivially) but not zero knowledge (assuming $f$ is indeed one-way).

Comment: Thank you, can't upvote yet. Beautiful.